# how to protect attributes from mass assignement

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mass-assignment

Hi I have a NOOB question in light of what happend at GITHUB with their application being exploited because of the security hole in Rails.

What is the best way to protect object attributes in Rails but still allow them to be assigned values where applicable?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually Rails 3.1 has added new built-in ways to handle mass-assignment with roles which is probably something that you want to take a look at.

Release notes [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/3_1_release_notes.html#active-record)

Basically it works like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  attr_accessible :name, :role, :as => :admin
end
```

What this enables you to do is that you can use the following way to allow the user to update his own information in one of your controllers:

```
@user.update_attributes(params[:user])
```

And that usage can never update the `:role` attribute in the User model. But when you have your admin users managing the roles in a separate controller, then you can user the following syntax:

```
@user.update_attributes(params[:user], :as => :admin)
```

And that will allow the `:role` attribute to be updated as well

Comment: Thanks DanneManne that helps. I will do just that.